# 2 Computers to the same Apache Server. WIRELESSLY

Tags: apache-http-server, networking

I'm trying to test my website and I must test it with **2 computers**.

How can I connect **2 computers** to the same *Apache Server* (**wirelessly**) **?**

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you provided more detailed information about what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, etc.

However, I assume you are attempting to use http://localhost or 127.0.0.1 to try an access them? If all computers are on the same network, just use the IP address of the server (i.e. http://192.168.1.102). Otherwise just use the external IP or domain your server is configured to use.

Comment: I think that is exactly what i was looking for. I'll just try it and then mark it as accepted answer... :)